# Google maps "send directions to your iPhone" on my mac no longer finds my iPhone

Tags: google-maps

For some reason google maps does not see my iPhone anymore from my `mac`: the only destination presented is my email:

[image]

This *was* working for the prior year that I have had this mac.  I did click on *Device not shown? Learn more* and it says to be logged in on both the mac and iPhone.  I *am* signed in on google to both of those devices.  Any ideas?

Comment: This question is technically on-topic, but I think you’re likely to get better/faster support from Google’s resources.  The Google “Send to Device” is centralized on their servers so if your iPhone isn’t being seen it’s something to do with their app not communicating to their server(s).  I would try signing out and back into the App (or even uninstall/reinstall) to ensure all authentication tokens are “fresh.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't very well documented by Google or Apple, so I can only suggest a few general troubleshooting steps you can try:

1. Make sure that both your Mac and iPhone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Restart both your Mac and iPhone to refresh their network connections.
3. Ensure that you are signed in to the same Google account on both devices (apparently you are - just check again to be sure). Also check that you are signed in with the same account and it's the selected one (if you're using multiple Google accounts).
4. On your iPhone, go to *Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services* and make sure that Location Services is enabled for Google Maps (can be a cause).
5. On your Mac, open System Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services and make sure that Location Services is enabled for Google Chrome or the browser you are using.
6. Try signing out and signing back in to your Google account on both devices.
7. Make sure you are running the [latest available version of Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3615175?sjid=17173988276370952539-EU&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0).
8. If the issue persists, you can try reinstalling the Google Maps app on your iPhone and clearing the cache and cookies on your Mac's browser.
9. If none of these steps resolve the issue, I recommend reaching out to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/).

Some of my solutions were taken from [Send directions to your phone or tablet](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6081481?hl=en&sjid=17173988276370952539-EU#zippy=%2Cmy-device-is-missing-as-an-option).

Comment: good list. i've mostly checked these off already, but one thing is i decided to acceleate upgrading to macOS 13.4.1

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Not sure how this may affect Google Maps not detecting your iPhone but might still be (possibly) helpful - could not cause harm at least. Have me informed when you have some new results (with 13.4.1)! ;)

Comment: Did not work on 13.4.X or on 13.5.X .  Blocked.  I end up cutting and pasting the link from the mac into the `Messages` app. This worked for years, not sure what changed/broke on google maps.

Comment: I've just tried on 13.5.2 - device isn't showing. I'll test on other browsers again.